# Set Colour Of Vector Image In Xcode 6+

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, ios8, xcode6, vector-graphics

I saw one of the Apple Videos mention that you can colour images via the code. All my searches on how to do this came up blank.

If I have a black vector image (pdf) saved inside Images.xcassets, how can I colour that image at run time?

Ideally it would be something simple like [UIImage setVectorColor:UIColorBlue] but I'm sure there could be more to it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to set all vectors image as **Template Image** on Render options in the xassets. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTuDC.png)

After, you can set the color in the uiimageview which contain your image with method :

```
[imageView setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Apparently you don't see the effect in the storyboard yet. Only at runtime.

Comment: I am able to see the tint color effects in Storyboard (Using Xcode 9.4)
Just make sure you are changing the render option to Template Image as mentioned by @edfanhouse